# Java how to marshall code on a network message

Tags: java, networking, server, marshalling, unmarshalling

This is a chat program that has a server and client side. The user sends a message to the server dictating what it is that the user wants to do. I am asked to marshall and unmarshall code for each of the message identifiers. I currently have an enumator containing every message along with the id value in the Server and Client classes. I also have an interface that is being implemented by every message identifier class. There are 7 message identifiers: REGISTRATION_MESSAGE, REGISTRATION_RESPONSE, DEREGISTRATION_MESSAGE, REQUEST_REGISTERED_USERS, RESPONSE_REGISTERED_USERS, BROADCAST_MESSAGE, and WHISPER_MESSAGE. All in all, I believe that if I can figure out the first message, I can do the other ones pretty easily. I am struggling to understand the concept, along with the know-hows for marshalling and unmarshalling. Currently, this is the snippet of code I am currently struggling on.
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ5wb.png)

I've never messed with bytes so that alone kind of confuses me. Oh, and also I suppose it might would be useful to show my interface, [interface code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoO28.png), along with my enumator declartion (in both Server and Client classes, but for the case of showing you I'll show just one since they are the same) [enumator code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXLC2.png)

Comment: Oh, and as you're new here: please NEVER post images of code. Insert the code into your questions, so we can copy/paste/replicate it easier. Best thing is to provide a minimal runnable example, so we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the Socket.InputStream you create a DataInputStream, which lets you read short, int, long etc. Use short or readUTF to read the ordinal/String for the message type, then `switch` on it, let each of the message type implementation handle its own I/O from there (best done in individual methods).